# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón realice dos acciones?

Tags: php, html

Me gustaría que al presionar un botón se envíe la información del formulario a una base de datos y que al mismo tiempo se abra otra pagina html. Este es el php para mandar la info a la base de datos

```
<?php
include("con_db.php");

if (isset($_POST ['boton'])) {

    if (strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['lista']) >= 1) {

        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $lista = trim($_POST['lista']);
        $fechareg = date("d/m/y");
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO datos(email, lista, fecha_reg) VALUES ('$email','$lista','$fechareg')";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);

        if ($resultado) {
             ?>
             <h3 class="ok">En unos momentos te llegará un correo</h3>
             <?php
        }
        else{
             ?>
             <h3 class="bad">UPS. Ha ocurrido un error</h3>
             <?php
        }
    }
        else {
             ?>
             <h3 class="bad">Plox complete los campos</h3>
             <?php
        }

    }

 ?>
```

`

La pagina que estoy creando es para que los clientes llenen unos datos y que despues puedan hacer un pago para obtener el servicio. Sólo quiero que la pagina sea lo menos complicada para ellos y sea practico. Me ayudan plox :C

Comment: Usa [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) con un location en la condición que quieras que eso ocurra, pero piensa que no veran el mensaje que pones.

Comment: *Sólo quiero que la pagina sea lo menos complicada para ellos y sea practico.* Entonces, considera usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch, para comunicar entre cliente y servidor sin necesidad de recargas de página o redirecciones a otras páginas.

Comment: Gracias :3, me sirvió mucho, me diste una idea y ya funcionó :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Añade al final del código la función:

header('Location: nueva_pagina.html');